# 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, redirect, permissions, xampp, http-status-code-403

Users are redirected once they logged in

```
//redirected when logged in
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\parentfolder/'. $_SESSION['name'];
chdir($dir);
```

This displays the folders inside the $dir and generate their links

```
<?php 
    $dir_open = opendir('.');
    $currentdir = getcwd();
    echo $currentdir;


    while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
        if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $link = "<a href='/$dir/$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
            echo $link;
        }
        
    }
    closedir($dir_open);
    ?>
```

The links redirects to the right directories(displayed in the address bar) but shows this error

**Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource.**

All of the folders are empty. Any tips to fix this?

Comment: _"The links redirects to the right directories"_ - do they really though? It looks like you are outputting file system paths there, whereas it should of course be URLs to begin with.

Comment: it seems i have problem with permission. I am unable to create new directory as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must grant privileges for folder